# Cannot access vsftpd server from WAN

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

EDIT: It has been fixed by adding pasv_addr_resolve=yes to the config file and setting iptables exception for passive range using this command: iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport pasvstart:pasvend -j ACCEPT

I have already port forwarded 20 and 21, and 50000-60000.

I cannot access the service from the LAN or Internet.

ftptest.net results:

```
Warning: Plaintext FTP is insecure. You should use explicit FTP over TLS.
Status: Resolving address of (public ip)
Status: Connecting to (public ip)
Warning: The entered address does not resolve to an IPv6 address.
Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...
Reply: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of 2a02:2788:74:1b5c:b91f:d77c:f39f:4352
Reply: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Command: USER nasftp
Reply: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS *********
Reply: 230 Login successful.
Command: SYST
Reply: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Command: FEAT
Reply: 211-Features:
Reply: EPRT
Reply: EPSV
Reply: MDTM
Reply: PASV
Reply: REST STREAM
Reply: SIZE
Reply: TVFS
Reply: UTF8
Reply: 211 End
Warning: The server does not indicate MLSD support. MLSD uses a well-specified listing format. Without MLSD, directory listings have to be obtained using LIST which uses an unspecified output format.
Command: PWD
Reply: 257 "/"
Status: Current path is /
Command: TYPE I
Reply: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command: PASV
Error: Connection timed out
```

Vsftpd config file:
http://pastebin.com/0JmDPsmv

Any help would be appreciated!